# Jquery Chosen Ajax call not rendering the options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-chosen

I am using Jquery 1.6.4 and chosen 1.4.1. I am facing issue while rendering the options from AJAX. Following is my code.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery(".chzn").data("placeholder","Select Frameworks...").chosen();
  jQuery("#item").chosen().change(function(e, params){
    values = jQuery("#item").chosen().val();
    $('#item_selected').val(values);
  });
 });


$('#customer').click(function() {
  
  var url = "ajax_common.php?action=getItem&companyid=1";
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data){
      $("#item option").remove();
      $("#item").append(data);
      $("#item").trigger("liszt:updated");
    }
  });
    </script>
```

```html
<select class="chzn inpt-fld" multiple="true" name="item" id="item" style="width: 96%">
</select>
```

But the value is not appending in the multi-select drop-down?

Answer (score 1):

The problem seem came from the way you output ajax response. You can not append options in the select tag dynamically because it is not belong to the current select. Meaning this select can not detect the options that previously not exist (as hard code).

You should include select and option together in ajax_common.php and render in div as innerHtml.

```
// inside ajax_commond.php :
<select class="chzn inpt-fld" multiple="true" name="item" style="width: 96%">
<option> xxxx </option>
</select>

// render the ajax response in : 
<div id="item"></div>
```